# How to pass data between fragments using ViewModel(s)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I use Koin and Fragment + ViewModel per screen.
In my HomeFragment I have list with post.
When user selects post I navigate user to PosDetailsFragment and I want to display info about post.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
               private val homeViewModel by viewModel<HomeViewModel>()

               //when user select post I set that value to LeadViewModel (I want to make that viewModel as common for some fragment)
               leadViewModel.state.selectedPost.value = action.post
}


class PostDetailsFragment : Fragment() {
        private val leadViewModel by sharedViewModel<LeadViewModel>()
    
        //always null
        val post = leadViewModel.state.selectedPost.value
}
```

My Koin module:

```
    viewModel { LeadViewModel() }
    viewModel { HomeViewModel(get(bottomNavigationCommander), get()) }
    viewModel { AddPostViewModel() }
```

What is wrong? It looks like instance of LeadViewModel in PostDetailsFragment is completely different than in HomeFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the val as backing field

```kotlin
        val post
          get() = leadViewModel.state.selectedPost.value
```

Comment: The same :( post in null

Comment: I just noticed that you are using different viewmodels in Home and PostDetailsFragment. Make sure to use the same viewmodel for both screens and having `by sharedViewModel` will take care of giving you the same instance inside `PostDetailsFragment`